# api recipe can't be installed due to minimum-stability

Tags: composer-php, symfony-3.3, symfony-flex, symfony-recipe

I would like to use `api-platform/api-platform` in my flex-enabled symfony application. To do so, I run the following commands:

```
# creation of the flex-enable symfony application
composer create-project symfony/skeleton:3.3.* sf-flex

# installation of the api recip
composer req api
```

Unfortunately, I am getting this error message:

**[InvalidArgumentException]

Could not find package api-platform/api-pack at any version for your minimum-stability (stable). Check the package spelling or your minimum-stability**

**require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--] []**

To avoid that problem, I tried several solutions:

**Solution 1**

```
composer create-project symfony/skeleton:3.3.x-dev sf-flex
composer req api
```

**SAME ERROR**

**Solution 2**

```
composer create-project symfony/skeleton:3.3.x-dev sf-flex # a more recent version of symfony/skeleton
composer req --dev api
```

**SAME ERROR**

**Solution 3**

I tried to update the file `composer.lock` by changing that field as follows:

```
# "minimum-stability": "stable", # has been changed to to dev
"minimum-stability": "dev",
```

**SAME ERROR**

So, any proposal??

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this [page](https://igor.io/2013/02/07/composer-stability-flags.html), I just changed `composer.json` by adding this line:

```
"type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",    // the added line
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
// ...
```

And the API recipe is installed without problems...